# How can I change the color of a plain frame in beamer with Metropolis theme?

Tags: beamer, color, beamer-metropolis

I'm trying to make some slides for an upcoming presentation with customized colors for the Metropolis theme. However, I'm having some trouble with changing the color for a plain frame (`\plain`). My code now looks like this:

```
{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=rugred}
\plain{Questions?}
}
```

Which results in:

[image: valid].

Also, `rugred`is a custom color, made by myself.

Could anyone help me out and tell me how I can fix this issue? The MWE is given by

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle, block=fill]{metropolis}
%\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\definecolor{rugred}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=rugred}
\setbeamercolor{plain}{bg=rugred}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Presentation}
\date{\today}
\author{Author\\ {\and}\\{Supervisor: \hspace{7.2mm} Supervisor}\\ {\and}{Second assessor: Second assessor}}
\institute{University}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=rugred}
\plain{Questions?}
}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}

  \bibliography{references}
  \bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I also having some trouble posting the screenshot, you can copy paste the link into your browser!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you! I just added a MWE.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the background color of `palette primary` to `rugred`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle, block=fill]{metropolis}
%\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\definecolor{rugred}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=rugred,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=rugred}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Presentation}
\date{\today}
\author{Author\\ {\and}\\{Supervisor: \hspace{7.2mm} Supervisor}\\ {\and}{Second assessor: Second assessor}}
\institute{University}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\plain{Questions?}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}

  \bibliography{references}
  \bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: @Lotvi, you could accept the answer if you like it.